# ASP.NET handle a POST from Sage Pay

Tags: c#, asp.net, generic-handler, opayo

I am writing an asp.net web application to talk to sage pay and make payments via their server to server method. At present my site collects user details and then sends a transaction registration HttpRequest to their server. Their server then responds to my request with some details and a redirect link. I check out the reponse object and then redirect to their payment page where the users payment details (card number etc) can be entered. Once the user has clicked confirm then sage will send a POST to a url of my choosing which I can then process and tell them whether to continue with the transaction or not.

What I am aiming to do is receive the POST from them, check the content and respond accordingly. I must then give them as part of my  success or failure url which their site will send the user too on completion of the transaction. If I were sending a request first it would be easy but I am not. They just need an address to send the response to and then I must process it.

My question is this. How can I handle an HttpRequest (I assume this is what it will be?) in my web application?

Can I do this by telling them to respond to a generic handler? If I were to give them the url of my generic handler could I process the POST in there and then respond to them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I do this by telling them to respond to a generic handler? If I
>   were to give them the url of my generic handler could I process the
>   POST in there and then respond to them?

The Generic Handler will work. You can handle the request parameters via `context.Request.Params`

Example:

```
public class Handler : IHttpHandler {

    public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {

    string someparamreturned = context.Request.Params["somekey"];
    //etc.. do something
    }

    public bool IsReusable {
    get {
        return false;
    }

}
```

You don't really need a full-blown up page to handle this.

Comment: Thanks for that. My situation is that my initial page will be loaded in a webbrowser control on a winforms app. My page then automatically sends the HTTPRequest to Sage on load. Next I redirect to sages own page. This part means I need the full page at first. Following that my handler (I am hoping) will be capable of receiving a POST and dealing with it. It should then respond to Sage who will then perform the final redirect back to a different page of mine. In your example does the Params collection hold each param passed to me by sage in their POST?

Comment: @CSharpened `In your example does the Params collection hold each param passed to me by sage in their POST?` Yes, absolutely. I understand the situation you are explaining because that's very similar to how Paypal and Google Wallet HTML APIs work and I happen to be doing something very similar at the moment.

Comment: Big thanks for the info Icarus. I have used generic handlers a lot for ajax etc but not really for HTTPRequests etc so was unsure as to what they were capable of. Google didnt turn up much of help.